# Flutter Project size exceeding limit on Git

Tags: git, flutter, bitbucket

My Current Flutter project size is around 1.62 GB .is it normal ? how can I analyse it? and On Git I am getting project size limit warning :

> This repository is over the 2.0 GB limit and you are not able to push
> new commits. To resolve this, contact your repository’s admin.

Please suggest how can I fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are pushing to GIthub or Gitlab or something else?

Comment: I am Pushing it on BitBucket

Comment: My .git file is taking 700 MB, in other projects it is normally takes 2-3 MB

Comment: can be a number of things: a large history, large files such as binaries and images... do you have anything of the sort?

Comment: yes inside git-->object--> pack there is a PACK file.it is size 686 MB, but i have no idea about this file,can it be removed?

Comment: I mean inside the files you are versioning.

Comment: you might be including the build folder, use .gitignore file to ignore files while commiting and pushing

Comment: .gitigonre flies already included inside android and iOS folder separeltey.do i need to change anything inside those files?@Yadu

Comment: The issue was that there was 2 gitignore files added in my project by mistake, so the original gitignore was not working, so i resolved the issue by updating my gitignore file then pushing it on Git, but still my project size is 1.1 GB on Git